# Improve the performance of a SQL Query via SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

I'm looking for improve the performance of the Last Year Attended query. Right now, its taking 20+ minutes to run this block.

The LYA take the most recent year attended for a particular event and finds the year they attended prior to the max. For example if they attended in 2018 for an event, the query will look for the last year attended prior to 2018.

LYA for 2018 should return a Null

The data should return the following:

```
CompanyID   MarketID    Industry    LAST YEAR ATTENDED
-------------------------------------------------------
123456      1234        GIFT        2018
123457      1234        HOME        2017
123458      1234        GIFT        2018
123459      1234        HOME        2018
123460      1234        APPAREL     2018
123461      1234        HOME        2018
123462      1234        HOME        2017
123463      1234        APPAREL     2018
```

Can anyone assist?

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    COMPANYID, MARKETID, INDUSTRY,
    [LAST YEAR ATTENDED] = (SELECT MAX(YEAR(attdate))
                            FROM v_marketatt va
                            WHERE va.companyid = vm.companyid
                              AND YEAR(attdate) <> (SELECT MAX(YEAR(attdate))
                                                    FROM v_marketatt vb
                                                    WHERE vb.companyid = vm.companyid)
                              AND MARKETCODE LIKE 'SM1%')
FROM
    v_marketatt vm
WHERE 
    MARKETID IN (835, 1032, 1101)
```

UPDATE:

Found that is version is more efficient than the rest. Run time down to 7 minutes on a clone. Instead of allowing the subquery to dip into my view twice, had it dip once.

```
select
DISTINCT COMPANYID,
MARKETID,
INDUSTRY,
CSTATUS,
[LAST YEAR ATTENDED] = (select max(year(attdate)) from v_marketatt va where year(attdate) <> (select max(year(attdate)) from v_marketatt) AND MARKETCODE LIKE 'SM1%' AND va.COMPANYID = vm.COMPANYID)
from v_marketatt vm
WHERE MARKETID IN (835,1032,1101)
;
```

Thanks to all who responded.

Comment: Please explain what the logic is supposed to do.  Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: what's the logic behind the last year attended?

Comment: The field [LAST YEAR ATTENDED] has a subquery that computes the max year on each iteration.You can try moving this piece of query to a join

Comment: Question #1: Your query gives you one result row per `COMPANYID, MARKETID, INDUSTRY`. Your sample result shows only one result row per `COMPANYID`. So is `COMPANYID + YEAR(attdate)` unique in the table? If not, what do you want: One row per  `COMPANYID, MARKETID, INDUSTRY` or one row per  `COMPANYID`?

Comment: Question #2: Is it on purpose that you apply `MARKETCODE LIKE 'SM1%'` only on the query to find the second year? Shall this be part of the real query or was this just for testing?

Comment: Thorsten since these type of markets happen once a year, its important to find which year was the last year they attended. This why I choose to use LIKE rather than "in" or "=".

Comment: @MikeBenton: out of curiosity, are you sure that this is really what you want?  Suppose `MARKETID 123` has a record in v_marketatt with attdate `1 jan 2020` and `MARKETID 835` has 2 records; one with `1 jan 2010` and one with `1 Jan 2011`; what do you want to get out of it and what do you think is coming out now?

Comment: @deroby I'm certain that is what I needed for the exercise I was performing. What you're asking is scenario that can never exist in our data unless other dependencies were keyed incorrectly and one of our systems was busted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The field [LAST YEAR ATTENDED]  has a subquery that computes the max year on each iteration.You can try moving this piece of query to a join something like

```
    select DISTINCT COMPANYID, MARKETID, INDUSTRY,
    [LAST YEAR ATTENDED] 
    from v_marketatt vm
    inner join 
    ( select max(year(attdate)) as [LAST YEAR ATTENDED]
                    from v_marketatt ivm 
           where year(ivm.attdate) <> (select max(year(attdate))
                                            from v_marketatt vb
                                            where vb.companyid = 
                 ivm.companyid)
       AND MARKETCODE LIKE 'SM1%')va on va.companyid = vm.companyid
          --where companyid not in (select distinct companyid from 
      v_marketatt where marketid in (602))
       WHERE MARKETID IN (835,1032,1101)
```

I have not run this query , there could be some minor corrections on syntax , but if you get the concept it should be easy to pick and fix.

Comment: Correlated subqueries run one row at a time and derived tables work in sets, so yes this should speed things up considerably. Correlated subqueries are a SQL Server code smell.

Comment: Yes , when there are complex nested subqueries , using aggregations , it is a good idea to try with join as it gets compiled and parsed by the sql parser and reduces the overheard.@Mike can you tell us if this logic worked for you.

Comment: I ended up tweaking your code a bit as it was missing a few components to make it run. It brought the run time down a lot on a cloned db which means it will run even faster on the production servers. I appreciate the assist.

Comment: Good to know it helped . There is no one way of approaching these issues , a lot depends on Sql parser settings, how it lays the execution plan.Also sometimes IO processing is the main problem for the latencies , then you can try the temp table which will use your temp db to share the IO file swapping load.The more you tune queries , experience will surely help.

Answer (score 0):

apologies for syntax, I'm throwing this together quickly. But I suspect making use a CTE should improve performance dramatically. I'm also not quite sure what you're doing here:

```
WHERE va.companyid = vm.companyid
                              AND YEAR(attdate) <> (SELECT MAX(YEAR(attdate))
                                                    FROM v_marketatt vb)
                              AND MARKETCODE LIKE 'SM1%'
```

So I've left that piece alone. Try something like this, which should help, and possible clarification on the part I've noted above might unlock other things to tweak.

```
;with Year_CTE (year)

as

(SELECT MAX(YEAR(attdate), va.companyid)
                            FROM v_marketatt va
                            WHERE va.companyid = vm.companyid
                              AND YEAR(attdate) <> (SELECT MAX(YEAR(attdate))
                                                    FROM v_marketatt vb)
                              AND MARKETCODE LIKE 'SM1%')

SELECT DISTINCT 
    COMPANYID, MARKETID, INDUSTRY,
    vb.[YEAR]
FROM
    v_marketatt vm
join Year_CTE vb on vb.companyid = vm.companyid
WHERE 
    MARKETID IN (835, 1032, 1101)
```

Answer (score 0):

IF you need 'the one before this one' I'd suggest to use `LEAD()` or `LAG()` functions. 
Although I'm not quite sure I fully understand your example (see Thorsten Kettners comments), going by the explanation I think what you want is something along the lines of:

```
;WITH years
   AS (
        SELECT COMPANYID, MARKETID, INDUSTRY, YEAR_ATTENDED = Year(attdate)
          FROM v_marketatt
          WHERE MARKETID IN (835, 1032, 1101)
           AND MARKETCODE LIKE 'SM1%' -- not sure about this one, the example isn't very clear
         GROUP BY COMPANYID, MARKETID, INDUSTRY, Year(attdate)
       ),
     last_ones
  AS (
        SELECT row_nbr = ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY  COMPANYID, MARKETID, INDUSTRY ORDER BY YEAR_ATTENDED DESC),
               COMPANYID, MARKETID, INDUSTRY, 
               LAST_YEAR_ATTENDED = YEAR_ATTENDED,
               PREV_YEAR_ATTENDED = LEAD(YEAR_ATTENDED, 1, NULL) OVER (PARTITION BY COMPANYID, MARKETID, INDUSTRY ORDER BY YEAR_ATTENDED DESC)
          FROM years
     )

SELECT COMPANYID, MARKETID, INDUSTRY, 
      LAST_YEAR_ATTENDED,
      PREV_YEAR_ATTENDED
 FROM last_ones
WHERE row_nbr = 1
```

Since I don't have the tables nor the data here, I haven't tested the query, but I hope it will get you going...

Comment: The issue with lag and lead is that I'd have to rank the years, then run again on rank. I appreciate the insights.

Comment: Isn't doing `MAX()` twice just as bad, if not worse?